# Permutation Optimization

Tags: optimization, permutation, simulation

I have a problem which requires me to find an optimal permutation. There are many elements, usually between 20-50 but sometimes less, sometimes more, and I must pick 10. I run simulations with the picked elements to arrive at a number between 0 and 1. The more Sims the more precision.

I need to find a method that is quick and sufficiently thorough. I know from experience the earlier on an element is picked the more impact it has on the result. Some elements have light synergy so it isn't sufficient to give a weight to the elements ahead of time.

Current Method:

I manually select the elements that I believe are closest to a solution and hill climb by swapping 1 value at a time between Sims. This succeeds in finding a local maximum but I would like to improve the odds of winding up in the absolute maximum.

Option 1:

I have considered generating a certain number of permutations that satisfy that they are all a certain degree of difference from one another and climbing each. The hope would be that if I was in a local maximum that one of the others could land within a different maximum group.

Option 2:

I have also considered simming a certain number of permutations and then giving each element a value. The sooner it appears in the list, the more it is weighted, and then scale the weight by the performance and combine all the values of that element. Then I have a dynamic rough estimation of performance per element.

Does this s problem resemble a known algorithm or can this problem be converted into another type of problem? Is there a custom solution that I can use?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What's the bottleneck in your application? Is it generating the permutations or running simulations with them? There are well-knwon algorithms to effectively generate permutations, but if your problem is the second case, you need to provide more details.

Comment: Individual simulations are relatively short but it requires a certain number of simulations to get an accurate average. I know how to iterate through each permutation and can run simulations off them, but this will take too long. I'd like to get the closest result for the least amount of time, leaning more towards a complete solution than a faster one. Generally the climb method that I use now runs for 5-30 minutes.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the structure of the problem, rather than the attempted solution? Perhaps it's feasible to automatically make inferences such as "this item is pretty good to have near the beginning" (if it consistently gives high scores regardless of the rest) or "X goes together well with Y" (if their combination is consistently better than either of them by themselves). Then you may guide the search using that information.

Comment: The problem is optimizing a card deck given a certain number of cards available. Elements (cards) have more impact on the end result (win/loss) at the beginning, and there is some notion of synergy (x and y do better together [where together might mean side by side, played a certain number of turns after, or just in the same permutation]) but it's slight. At this point I'm more interested with how the problem is solved than the solution that can be achieved.